# List all items from a for loop with javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm looking for a way to list each firstname from the below loop. Currently it loops through each firstname stoping at the last which is Jack and only displaying that. I want it to display all of them like: John, Jane, Joe

```
var person = [{firstName:"John"}, {firstName:"Jane"}, {firstName:"Jack"}];

for (var i = 0; i < person.length; i++) {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = person[i].firstName;
}
```

Can anyone advise on how I would do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your are overwriting the `innerHTML` value, instead that you need to append your values to `innerHTML` property using **'+'**:

```
var person = [{firstName:"John"}, {firstName:"Jane"}, {firstName:"Jack"}];
var demo = document.getElementById("demo");

for (var i = 0, len = person.length; i < len; i++) {
  demo.innerHTML += person[i].firstName + ' ';
}
```

Check out this [codepen](http://codepen.io/ianaya89/pen/ByoZRZ). I have add some modifications to make the code more performant.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this code:

```
var person = [{firstName:"John"}, {firstName:"Jane"}, {firstName:"Jack"}],
html = "";

for (var i = 0; i < person.length; i++) {
 html += person[i].firstName;
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = html;
```

You are overwriting each time with the innerHTML because you are not using '+='. I like to create a string beforehand and set it to nothing. Then you can add everything to that and only need to call innerHTML once.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

here's another way to do it using a more [functional](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/07/02/dont-be-scared-of-functional-programming/) style

```js
"use strict";

var people = [{firstName:"John"}, {firstName:"Jane"}, {firstName:"Jack"}];

var node = document.getElementById('demo');

node.innerHTML = people.map(function(person){
  return person.firstName;
}).join(', ');
```

```css
#demo {
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #def;
  border: 1px solid gray
}
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```